# Python - Add boolean condition to generator

Tags: python, generator

I am generating tuples using :

```
Z = 1
W = 5
[(x,y) for x in range(Z-2,Z+2)for y in range(W-2,W+2)]
```

I would like to incorporate some boolean conditions to this generator such as :

1. Don't include tuples where x equals y.
2. Don't include tuples where x is non positive.

Is there a dedicated syntax for this task? Something like :

```
[(x,y) for x in range(Z-2,Z+2)for y in range(W-2,W+2) where (x!=y) and (x>0)]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I interpret non-positive numbers to include 0 so the conditions end up being

1. x != y
2. x >= 0

So the comprehension becomes:

```
>>> [(x,y) for x in range(Z-2,Z+2) for y in range(W-2,W+2) if x != y and x >= 0]
[(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6)]
```

Another example: Select the numbers between 0 and 99 (inclusive) whose remainder of division for both 2 and 3 equals 0.

```
>>> [ i for i in range(100) if (i%2==0) and (i%3==0)]
[0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 66, 72, 78, 84, 90, 96]
```

Generally you could describe the syntax as

```
[ result for variables in iterable if condition ]
```

Comment: Every number divisible by 4 is divisible by 2, so there actually is no need for the first test since you're just producing multiples of 4. :P

Comment: @SukritKalra Good point *faceplam* I'll make a better example

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter on the generator

```
filter (lambda i:i[0]!=i[1] and i[0]>0, ((x,y) for x in range(Z-2,Z+2)for y in range(W-2,W+2))
```